# Drupal 7 - How to display the number of nodes for each term in the expanded filter?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Fields in my view:

```
Commerce: Photo
Commerce: Header
Commerce: Price
```

In the filtering criteria:

```
Content: Has taxonomy term
```

for each vocabulary as a drop-down list. Also, using Better Exposed Filter each term shows as a checkbox.

I would like to add count of nodes (in my case - products) matching the taxonomy term, for example:

```
Best (3)
New (2)
Discounts (4)
```

I tryied this - http://kalpanagoel.com/node/3
but this only works when the dictionaries in the fields.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [search api](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api) and [facet api](https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi) modules to do so.

Screenshot from facet api module.
[image: Screenshot from facet api module]